# how service in angular-2 gets value dynamically in every component?

Tags: angular, angular-services

i had created a service in angular-2 application eg: AuthService and i had multiple components in my app in one of the component(signUpComponet) i will get the user data when registered, then i what to initialize with AuthService and i want to use this AuthService in every component.

so i finally want to call a service which dynamically gets data in every component i initialized to maintain the user in every component.

> *I had created service to store the session of the user using window property in html*

### my service

@Injectable()

```
export class AuthService {
Authentication(){
    var _this = this;
    _this._data = {
      user: window.data
    };
    return _this._data;
}
}
```

### signUpComponent

```
export class signUpComponent{

goToSigUp(user){
//calling backend service to fetch user data as response
 this.AuthService.Signup(user).subscribe(result => {
      if(result.type == false){
        this.errMsg = result.data;
      }else{
        this.authentication = result;// when data successfully retrieves call AuthService to store user as a window session and use in it this service in every component?   
      }   

    });
}
}
```

I hope this clear, i have no idea how to call that service when user arrives as a callback as i am newly learning angular.

Comment: 1)Provide the service in your root module(app). 2)Create a field in that service. 3) Update that field whenever you like

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your service as provider in app.module

```
@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
],
declarations: [AppComponent,

],
providers: [AuthService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

})
export class AppModule { }

Now setting the **this.authentication** will be accessible everywhere.

Hope it helps!!